# calling remote div using bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a lot of time trying to call a remote div using bootstrap's modals but when I call the remote file, it calls the full page, and I just need to get just a div from that remote page

what can I do... here a litte piece of code I'm using to call the remote page

```
<!-- menu list -->
                <li class="left"><a href="register.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal"><?php echo $lg["sign_up"]; ?></a></li>
```

and here is the remote page:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $lg["name"]; ?></title>

    <!-- Header Links -->
    <?php require("includes/inc.headerlinks.php"); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- This is our beautiful menu bar -->
    <?php require("frames/frame.topbar.php"); ?>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="body">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Modal Body</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

an example, when you go to http://www.mercadolibre.com.ve/ and you click on "inscribete" it brings you a div from the remote page (not the full page), that is what I want.

Comment: Since you get the whole page, you can extract the div from the page.

Comment: yeah, but what's the way to extract just the div and not the whole page?...

Comment: At the end of event, do javascript document.getElementByID(divid). Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to get only one specific div from the remote page instead of the whole page.

Comment: I checked the website, the registration holds a iframe, which links to https://registration.mercadolibre.com.ve/registration/?mode=lite&parent_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mercadolibre.com.ve%2F, if you open that url in browser, you will get the form only. So it is not like you suggested that the form is extracted from a page but the server only returns the specific form. Please try it yourself.

Comment: Really thanks for helping me to figure it out @Danyu but at the end I take the decision to use JQuery and the load function $('.signup').load('register.php #signup'); so really thanks for helping me again.